# OpenGL glReadPixels doesn't return when width%4 == 0?

Tags: opengl

I'm working with glReadPixels for some work, and it's behaving strangely. In particular, I run the following test:

```
unsigned char pixels[ 512 * 512 * 4 ];

int mid = 0;
while (mid < 512) {
  printf("Test %d : ", mid);
  memset(pixels, 0, 512*512*4);
  pixels[1] = 0x42;
  glReadPixels( 0, 0, mid, 511, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
  printf(" %x ", pixels[1]);
  if (pixels[0] == 0) {
    printf("0\n");
  } else {
    printf("1\n");
  }
  mid++;
}
```

With output:

```
Test 0 :  42 0
Test 1 :  67 1
Test 2 :  67 1
Test 3 :  67 1
Test 4 :  42 0
Test 5 :  67 1
Test 6 :  67 1
Test 7 :  67 1
Test 8 :  42 0
Test 9 :  67 1
Test 10 :  67 1
Test 11 :  67 1
```

I have already drawn data to the entire screen (the 0x67 is the correct byte for the color I'm drawing) so I'm not sure what's going on here.

The main thing I actually want is to get a copy of every pixel currently on the screen inside of an array I can access not on the GPU. I'm not sure if this is the 'correct' way about getting it, but it's the only way I know of. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What is your purpose of reading all those pixels? If you can tell us what you want to do with that data, we might be able to offer you an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code to first create an empty texture (use it just once, before your update loop):

```
GLuint texID;

GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(width*height*4*sizeof(GLubyte));
ZeroMemory(data,width*height*4*sizeof(GLubyte));

glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)texID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Then use the following to copy the current buffer to your texture (use this at the end of every update loop, just before you swap buffers):

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texID);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, width, height, 0);
```

And finally use this to retrieve an array with RGBA pixel data (right after the previous bit):

```
GLubyte *pixels = (GLubyte*)malloc(width*height*4*sizeof(GLubyte));
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texID);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

It all depends on what you want to do with this pixel data ofcourse. This may not help you at all, but I hope it will ;).